# How to execute Window Batch file having logging Credential from Another Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

We have windows 7 batch **'Test.bat'** file having below command

```
cd **Checkout Path**
CALL xms.bat
```

Now we have another bat file **'xms.bat'** file to execute below command

```
deploy-xcp-application --war-file <Application War filename with full Path> --configuration-file <Configuration filename with full path> --environment <name> --deployment-method <method> --data-policy maintain --validateonly false --xploreindexing true
```

Now to open separately the **'xms.bat'** file we have to provide login credential to execute above command.

So our requirement is that we will execute **'Test.bat'** file to call **'xms.bat'** but as to execute command from **'xms.bat'** file we have to provide login credential from **'Test.bat'** to **'xms.bat'**

How we can do that? Please let me know if you need any more clarification regarding my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a file to store the credentials in but that isn't very protected. you can do it like this.
Create a file in the same location as the .bat and put in it:
username=%enter_username_here%
password=%enter_password_here%
save it and exit.
in your .bat file as the login put this:

```
:login
echo Please enter your user name.
echo.
set /p username=: 
if exist %username%.txt (
goto load
) else (
exit
)

:load
for /f %%a in (%username%.txt) do set %%a
cls
echo Please enter your password.
echo.
set /p password1=: 
if %password1%==%password% (
goto %AFTER LOGGED IN%
) else (
echo Wrong password, Please try again
timeout 2 >nul /nobreak
goto load
)
```

Then to save all you variables put:

```
(echo var=%var%)>> %username%.txt
```

Hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Exact requirement is we have a two bat file, 'Test.bat' and 'xms.bat'.
if double click on 'xms.bat' it will ask for user id and password, then only you can run command.

In 'Test.bat' we have few commands to be executed and then call 'xms.bat' from 'test.bat' to execute last command and have to pass user id and password for 'xms.bat' so that automatically login to 'xms.bat' and execute command.

Then schedule 'test.bat' so that all command executed automatically.
How we can pass id and pw for 'xms.bat' from 'test.bat', then automatically login to 'xms.bat' and execute last command?

Comment: Sorry im a bit late,

Comment: I think i know what your trying to do. Your trying to execute xms.bat from test.bat but without having to log back in? If you are then you may have to create another file with the code from xms.bat and execute the other file from test.bat. I would create a file called xms2.bat then copy the code except the login from xms.bat to xms2.bat.

Comment: Sorry we have to login to xms.bat as by this login we will connect to server and execute command to deploy on the server. So can it be possible to call with login credential to xms.bat from test.bat providing credential dynamically? Login credential cam be hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joseph for the reply.

I am telling you my exact requirement. We have a two bat file. One is 'Test.bat' and another is 'xms.bat'.

Now if you double click on 'xms.bat' it will ask for user id and password, then only you can run command.

Now in 'Test.bat' we have certain command to be executed and once done we have call 'xms.bat' from 'test.bat' to execute another command. That time from 'test.bat' we have pass user id and password for 'xms.bat' so that automatically login to 'xms.bat' and execute last command.

We will then window schedule 'test.bat' so that all command executed automatically at certain time every day.

My question is that how we can pass user id and password for 'xms.bat' from 'test.bat' automatically, so that automatically login to 'xms.bat' and execute last command?

Please let me know if you have any doubts?